# could functions compress() / compress2() from zlib be parallelized without breaking serial inflate()

Tags: parallel-processing, zlib, deflate, inflate

I am trying to parallelize compression calls from zlib (compress / compress2 functions), where data to be compressed and output buffer is available at call time. For help I am following the code of pigz (https://zlib.net/pigz/) which is a utility and deals with files, so I would have to write something similar but able to intercept calls to compress/compress2. Furthermore I am assuming calls to compress/compress2 functions would be with reasonable data sizes, so parallelizing would make sense. also assuming transparent serial decompression by application using inflateInit_ / inflate / inflateEnd functions. also considering compromise on compression ratio.

1. I don't completely understand how write thread in pigz deals with outputs from multiple compress threads, which are not on byte boundary?
2. if there is a sync marker with certain space overhead, could that ever violate output buffer size given to compress/compress2 function call?
3. would this deflate stream generated in parallel, be transparently processed in serial by inflate call.